# Validating a date to be within the SqlDbType.DateTime range

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, ado.net, sqldbtype

I want to validate a System.DateTime value before I add it as a parameter to my SqlCommand instance.

The MSDN documentation for the SqlDbType enumeration says:

**Date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 to an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds.**

To validate the value, I'm using

```
public readonly DateTime SqlDateTimeMin = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
public readonly DateTime SqlDateTimeMax = new DateTime(9999, 12, 31);

if (value < SqlDateTimeMin || value > SqlDateTimeMax)
    // Validation check fails
else
    // Validation check succeeds
```

Is this the best way?  Is there an alternative to hard coding these min and max values?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about [SqlDateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx) and [SqlDateTime.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.maxvalue.aspx)?

Note: these are *SQL* type min/max not the .net types like the previous 2 answers :-)

Comment: +1 - that looks like it is *exactly* what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Eyes are going bad this late in the afternoon. My mistake.

Comment: To expand upon this, if you need to check a regular DateTime (something I've stumbled upon), remember that SqlDateTimes expose a Value property, which is a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDateTime.MaxValue = 12/31/9999
SqlDateTime.MinValue = 1/1/1753
```

Your code would then read:

```
if (value < SqlDateTime.MinValue || value > SqlDateTime.MaxValue)
```

I think this meets your needs better than `DateTime.MaxValue` and `DateTime.MinValue`, because `DateTime.MinValue` is not 1/1/1753 but rather is 1/1/0001.

Answer (score -6):

I think the real question is why is your users entering dates outside of this range?  Your code to validate it is fine, however I'd suggest it's a larger problem in the UI where people can enter bogus dates.

Comment: For some of us, it's easy to make a typo in a date. Or to misunderstand the date format (mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: Give them a date picker and disable the textbox.  That's how I roll... :-)

Comment: what about the birthday of ancient people